# Find index of a dynamic multidimensional array/json with matches id

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

thanks for checking,
I have a dynamic array which will contain multiple item/object.
I want the index number of this array, if a provided id matches with one of its contained

> But Because it is a dynamically generated array/json
>   it can have any amount of multidimensional array inside child items and so on and so forth.

so is there any way to find the index number with matches id.

```
var data = [
            {

                id:1,
                child:[
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        child: [
                            {
                                id: 3,
                                child: []
                            },
                            {
                                id:4,
                                child:[
                                    {
                                        id:44,
                                        child:[
                                            {
                                                id:55,
                                                child:[]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]

                    },
                    {
                        id:5,
                        child:[
                            {
                                id:6,
                                child:[]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Suppose i want to get the index of array where id is equal to 4.
I need to develop a logic/function which will return -> `data[0]['child'][0]['child'][1]`

Comment: nice idea, and what have you tried?

Comment: Not much because, i have no idea how to loop through an unknown amount of array which contains more than one index. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it recursively

```
function findId(obj, id, currentPath = "") {
    // Go through every object in the array
    let i = 0;
    for (let child of obj) {
        // If id matches, return
        if (child.id == id) return currentPath + `[${i}]`;
        // Else go through the children, if we find anything there, return it
        let next = findId(child.child, id, currentPath + `[${i}]['child']`);
        if (next) return next;
        i++;
    }

    // We didn't find anything
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @Ahadul Should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could take a complete dynmaic approach with knowing some keys.

```js
function findPath(object, id) {
    var path;

    if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return;
    if (object.id === id) return [];

    Object.entries(object).some(([k, o]) => {
        var temp;
        if (temp = findPath(o, id, path = [])) {
            path = [k, ...temp];
            return true;
        }
    });
    return path;
}

var data = [{ id: 1, child: [{ id: 2, child: [{ id: 3, child: [] }, { id: 4, child: [{ id: 44, child: [{ id: 55, child: [] }] }] }] }, { id: 5, child: [{ id: 6, child: [] }] }] }];

console.log(findPath(data, 44));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```